# Angular 9 Frontend / ASP.Net C# MVC Backend

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, angular9

Looking for information on whether it's possible to have an Angular 9 Frontend with a C# MVC Backend that only uses controllers, models and a class for functions? I.e ASP.Net but without the frontend views.

The applications would be in separate solutions within the same folder structure.

Comment: No. Don't make it over complicated. Use Angular 9 for web page development and use Web API as the middle tier.

Comment: So all within the same solution. Ok, sounds doable! That all then links to a MySQL DB which is straightforward enough. Appreciated

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota, I don't agree with you. Has perfect sense (And, e.g. it's more easy control Authorization), the only thing you need is create a HomeController that return an view "as the index.html" generated by Angular. Even in .NET there're official templates for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Having a Angular front end consuming a .net core API is a classic combo. There are dozens of tutorials on the Web. Alternatively Pluralsight has a great course that steps you though the process.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create different solutions to achieve what you planned to do.

If you are using Visual Studio, create a solution with a Web API project and use dotnet CLI to create an Angular JS project in that your solution folder.

Alternatively, you can do the above with the following CLI commands.

- Have a folder with your preferred project name maybe your on desktop
- Open the folder in a terminal (i.e either PowerShell, command prompt, git etc) and execute the following commands

  ```
  dotnet new webapi -o backend 
  ng new clientapp (follow the terminal on-screen instructions to complete the creation)
  ```

Kindly watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fom80TujpYQ&t=1090s